# Subquery returned more than 1 value and not permitted

Tags: count, sql-server-2008-r2

i have this select query to show a a table

```
select distinct 
   a.afdeling as AFD,  
   convert(varchar(10),DateAdd(Day, DateDiff(Day, 0, a.datetrans) , 0),103) as datetrans  ,
   convert(varchar(10),DateAdd(Day, DateDiff(Day, 0, a.doe ), 0),103) as inputdate,  
   (select COUNT(distinct a.DOE)  from detail a left join
      estate b on a.CodeEstate=b.Code   group by
      a.afdeling, a.datetrans , convert(varchar(10),DateAdd(Day, DateDiff(Day, 0, a.DOE ) ,0),103)
      ) as total ,
   datediff(DAY,a.datetrans,a.DOE) as variant , 
   GetDiffStatus(a.datetrans,a.DOE) as status from
   detail a  left join
   estate b on a.CodeEstate=b.Code  where b.name='Estate 1' and convert(varchar(10),DateAdd(Day, Datediff(Day, 0,
   a.datetrans), 0),103)  between '01/01/2013' and '31/01/2013' Group
   BY a.datetrans, a.doe,DateDiff(Day, 0, a.doe),a.afdeling  order by
   a.afdeling, a.datetrans, a.inputdate  , a.variant,
   a.status
```

what i'm trying to do is to count total DOE whith same date in one table, based on name in other table (estate) that have a key in table detail , but when i use that query it shown an error 
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

how to solve this problem , i'm using SQL Server 2008 r2 , thankyou

Answer (score 1):

The subquery has a `GROUP BY` clause, but no `WHERE` clause to correlate it with the outer query.  Thus it results in more than one value.  Since you are using the (presumably single) value of the subquery expression as a column value you get an error.

The confusion is enhanced by using the same aliases in both the subquery and outer query.

You want to look for additional information on *correlated subquery*.

Comment: yes ,i use single value in my subquery , and about the same aliases, basicaly , i count a data from same table , that's why it looks like  the aliases are the same. And about correlated subquery, can you give a brief explanation about that ? i'm kinda nubi on this sql query things , thanks

Comment: Try running just the subquery.  If it works, and returns more than one value, then you have a problem.  The outer `select` is, in effect, saying for eah row I want a value for each of the following columns returned.  You've asked for one of those values to have several values at once.  You can read up on correlated subqueries [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213263(v=sql.80).aspx) for a start.